# Problem with the display of Cyrillic characters in a pdf with lib itext

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, itext7, cyrillic

In the PDF document, you need to display the text in Russian. Many ways were used, but the result is the same - instead of letters "krazyabry". The text in English is displayed as intended.

Used:

- Android JDK + Kotlin
- iText 7.2.5

Name of font assets is const

```
const val fontName = "roboto.ttf"
```

Screenshot of assets folder

[image]

The font is added at creation

```
return@map PdfTextFormField
  .createText(outputDoc, it.wrapper, it.type.fieldName, it.v, font, 10f)
  .setJustification(1)
```

Output

[image]

### **Try #1**

```
protected val font: PdfFont by lazy {
  val asset = context.assets.open(fontName).readBytes()
  return@lazy PdfFontFactory.createFont(asset, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED)
}
```

*Result: no crash, no russian symbols*

### **Try #2**

```
protected val font: PdfFont by lazy {
    val asset = context.assets.open(fontName).readBytes()
    return@lazy PdfFontFactory.createFont(asset, PdfEncodings.CP1250, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED)
  }
```

*Result: no crash, no russian symbols*

### **Try #3**

```
protected val font: PdfFont by lazy {
    val asset = context.assets.open(fontName).readBytes()
    return@lazy PdfFontFactory.createFont(asset, "Cp1251", PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED)
  }
```

*Result: no crash, no russian symbols*

### **Try #4**

```
protected val font: PdfFont by lazy {
    return@lazy PdfFontFactory.createFont("/assets/arial.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED)
}
```

*Result: no crash, no russian symbols*

### **Try #5**

```
protected val font: PdfFont by lazy {
    return@lazy PdfFontFactory.createFont("/assets/arial.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED)
}
```

*Result: no crash, no russian symbols*

### **Try #6**

```
protected val font: PdfFont by lazy {
    return@lazy PdfFontFactory.createFont("/assets/arial.ttf", "Cp1251", PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED)
}
```

*Result: no crash, no russian symbols*

### **Try #7**

```
protected val font: PdfFont by lazy {
        return@lazy PdfFontFactory.createFont( "/system/fonts/Comic.ttf", PdfEncodings.UNICODE_BIG_UNMARKED, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED)
}
```

*Result:  java.io.IOException: /system/fonts/Comic.ttf not found as file or resource*

### **Try #8**

```
protected val font: PdfFont by lazy {
        return@lazy PdfFontFactory.createFont( "/system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED)
}
```

*Result: no crash, no russian symbols*

Try with encodoing: UTF8, UNICODBIG (error),  UNICODEBIG_UNMARKED (error)
**error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=128; index=128**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? You need a font that has the relevant glyphs and `arialuni.ttf` is one of them:

```
protected val font: PdfFont by lazy {
    return@lazy PdfFontFactory.createFont("/assets/arialuni.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED)
}
```

Just make sure to find the right font file (.ttf file)

Comment: I tried different fonts that support Russian characters.